# How an applied magnetic field breaks the inversion symmetry in a centrosymmetric system?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, symmetry-breaking, crystals, non-linear-systems

I want to understand why magnetic dipole transition breaks the inversion symmetry in a centrosymmetric system and gives rise to second-order nonlinearity.

Comment: Can you explain more what you are asking? Give some background information?

Comment: we know second order nonlinear optical susceptibility is zero in a centrosymmetric system. So the nonlinear phenomena like sum frequency generation, SHG and DFG which require second order nonlinearity are absent in centrosymmetric system. But this symmetry can be broken by applying a magnetic field . For e.g. in  centrosymmetric magnetic semiconductors like EuTe and EuSe electric dipole SHG is forbidden, however by applying magnetic field SHG is possible. I am mentioning the reference: DOI:https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.81.155201